# Compatibility of a .NET dll built by MATLAB R2013a with VS2010

Tags: c#, matlab, visual-studio-2010, dll, visual-studio-2015

I have a MATLAB function and I used MATLAB deploytool to compile a .NET dll out of it.
this dll works pretty well on VS2015 but when I try to use it in VS2010 it fails and gives the exception "debugger is attached but not configured to debug this unhandled exception."(Like snapshot below). any ideas? I really need to use this dll in VS2010. I should note that I have MCR installed. and my matlab is 32bit version.
[Exception printScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyCc4.png)

```
         Edge.Sobel sobel = new Edge.Sobel();
         string path1 = @"C:\Users\Mohammad_Homayooni\Desktop\mohseni\Images\landsat\LT51640352011014KHC00_B1.TIF";

        //voroodi haye method e "edgeDetect" (dakhele sobel)
        MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWNumericArray left = new MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWNumericArray(new double());
        MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWNumericArray bottom = new MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWNumericArray(new double());
        MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWNumericArray pixelsize = new MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWNumericArray(new double());
        MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWCharArray path = new MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWCharArray(path1); //string path = @"address e file e image"

        left = 5000; //baraye test ye adade alaki bezar felan
        bottom = 5000; //baraye test ye adade alaki bezar felan
        pixelsize = 10; //baraye test ye adade alaki bezar felan

        object result = null;

        //file e daryafti az matlab. ("1" tedade khoroojihaye function e matlab hast ke inja baraye ma hamoon 1 monaseb hast)
        result = sobel.edgeDetect(1, left, bottom, pixelsize, path);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Matlab 2011 32bit to build the dll and the problem is now resolved. It was compatibility problem.